# Trying to setup a PHP daemon using System_Daemon and I'm having issues getting it to run

Tags: ubuntu, php, daemon

I get the following error when trying to start a daemon using Ubuntu 10.04 and the PHP5:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'usr/lib/php5/20060613/pcntl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20060613/pcntl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Does System_Daemon try to call pcntl? If so, why is it looking for the file where it does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

System_Daemon uses the pcntl functions, but System_Daemon isn't loading the extension. The extension is defined in your php.ini and is loaded by PHP. Make sure you have compiled PHP with pcntl support (--enable-pcntl), if you are using the Ubuntu packages you might take a look at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=549953.

The extension directory can also be defined in the php.ini with the `extension_dir` key, make sure it is pointing to the correct directory. Multiple php.ini files may exists, so take a look and check if your extension configuration matches in each file. A specific PHP CLI configuration named php-cli.ini may exists.